C# Entity Framework Core - Get Parent with filtered child collections
I have approximately next domain models:
public partial class ParentEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<ChildA> ChildAs { get; set; } = new List<ChildA>();
    public virtual ICollection<ChildAHistory> ChildAHistories { get; set; } = new List<ChildAHistory>();
}

public partial class ChildA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentEntityId { get; set; }
    public string Data1 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Data2 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual ParentEntity ParentEntity { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<ChildAHistory> ChildAHistories { get; set; } = new List<ChildAHistory>();
}

public partial class ChildAHistory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentEntityId { get; set; }
    public int ChildAId { get; set; }
    public string Data1 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Data2 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual ParentEntity ParentEntity { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ChildA ChildA { get; set; } = null!;
}

Let's say I have the following data in DB:
// parent #1
{
  "id": 11,
  "name": "parent1",
  "childAs": [...],
  "childAHistories": [...]
}
// parent #2
{
  "id": 22,
  "name": "parent2",
  "childAs": [...],
  "childAHistories": [...]
}
// parent #1 \ child #1
{
  "id": 1,
  "parentEntityId": 11,
  "data1": "aa",
  "data2": "text2",
  "comments": "",
  "parentEntity": "<parent object>",
  "childAHistories": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "parentEntityId": 11,
      "childAId": 1,
      "data1": "tt",
      "data2": "aa",
      "comments": "",
      "parentEntity": "<parent object>",
      "childA": "<childA object>"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "parentEntityId": 11,
      "childAId": 1,
      "data1": "aa",
      "data2": "bb",
      "comments": "",
      "parentEntity": "<parent object>",
      "childA": "<childA object>"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "parentEntityId": 11,
      "childAId": 1,
      "data1": "aa",
      "data2": "aa",
      "comments": "",
      "parentEntity": "<parent object>",
      "childA": "<childA object>"
    }
  ]
}
// parent #2 \ child #2
{
  "id": 2,
  "parentEntityId": 22,
  "data1": "bb",
  "data2": "text2",
  "comments": "",
  "parentEntity": "<parent object>",
  "childAHistories": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "parentEntityId": 22,
      "childAId": 2,
      "data1": "tt",
      "data2": "aa",
      "comments": "",
      "parentEntity": "<parent object>",
      "childA": "<childA object>"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "parentEntityId": 22,
      "childAId": 2,
      "data1": "bb",
      "data2": "bb",
      "comments": "",
      "parentEntity": "<parent object>",
      "childA": "<childA object>"
    }
  ]
}

I need to return while collection of parents and child (ChildA) that includes sub-child (ChildAHistory) and at the same time filter sub-childs based on criteria. Such as return collection on parents with childs and historical records that contains "data1" = "aa" and filters out all other sub-childs from there.
I tried of using .Any(o => o..), but it returns only boolean, so as result it returns everything and doesn't filter the data.
var response = _context.ParentEntities
                   .Include(o => o.ChildAs)
                   .ThenInclude(o => o.ChildAHistories)
                   .Where(o => o.ChildAs.Any(o => o.Data1 == "aa"))
                   .Where(o => o.ChildAHistories .Any(o => o.Data1 == "aa"));

Not sure if I'm looking on my problem from right perspective.
Any advice are welcome!

For filtering out like that you should't use where method, you should use Select in these situations, like below:
var response = _context.ParentEntities
    .Select(parent => new 
    {
        Id = parent.Id,
        Name = parent.Name,
        ChildAs = parent.ChildAs
            .Where(childA => childA.Data1 == "aa")
            .Select(childA => new 
            {
                Id = childA.Id,
                ParentEntityId = childA.ParentEntityId,
                Data1 = childA.Data1,
                Data2 = childA.Data2,
                Comments = childA.Comments,
                ChildAHistories = childA.ChildAHistories
                    .Where(history => history.Data1 == "aa")
                    .ToList()
            })
            .ToList()
    })
    .Where(parent => parent.ChildAs.Any())
    .ToList();

Inside the select method itself, you should add the needed conditions.

this worked out. I just thought that there are better option that won't require manual mapping.
